# Move .exe file from development to test sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint

I have written a console application which updates certain fields/columns in sharepoint when it is executed.

This generates a .exe file in vs 2008. Now I would like to execute it on the test server how do I move the .exe file from Dev to test. I tried copying the exe file but it gave an error.

Please let me know.

Comment: An error? You don't think maybe it'd help to know what that error was?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the entire contents of the bin directory to the server, not just the single exe.